# TSQL: Insert several nibbles at given position of a hex string

Tags: sql-server, string, common-table-expression

I have the following table to generate a hex string for each ID to convert it later into binary. My problem is that the NibblePositions have gaps for every Nibble equals '0' because of performance generating this table based on greater 2 million records and several joins.

```
ID NibblePosition Nibble
 1              5    'A'
 1              9    '4'
 1             75    '3'
 .              .     .
 .              .     .
 1            198    '4'
 2              2    'E'
 2              5    'D'
 .              .     .
 .              .     .
 2            237    '2'
 3              .     .
 .              .     .
 .       max. 240     .
```

=>

```
ID HexString
 1 '0000A0004000...'
 2 '0E00D0000000...'
 ...
```

My first idea was to create an "empty" hex string using "replicate('0', 240)", and filling this string replacing the '0' at each NibblePosition using "stuff(hexString, NibblePosition, 1, Nibble)". But I don't know how to realize this with a CTE and grouped by ID.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

Comment: what i don't see is why you store data this way? what's the reason for that?

Comment: it's for data compression. I have millions of timestamps for each ID and want to store them bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
tally contains numbers from 1 to 240.

```
declare @nibble varchar(240)
Select @nibble  = ISNULL(@nibble,'')+CONVERT(varchar, isnull(h.nibble, 0))
    from Tally t
    left join Hexatable h on h.nibbleposition = t.id
    where Id = @Id
```